# laravel 5.1 route direct to public folder

Tags: .htaccess, routes, laravel-5.1

this is my route to access index.php ....http://localhost/abc/public/
if i write http://localhost/abc/ it does pick public bydefault

i want to write .htaccess file to direct http://localhost/abc call to http://localhost/abc/public/ 
so my url will not hurt..

in short i want http://localhost/abc/ and by dont even change directory struture of laravel.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

this gives error like

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself, it was so damn easy.
just change server.php file to index.php and change the file paths to public folder and u will be all set to go.

Answer (score 1):

To remove public from url you can try this..

> Important: Add following code in your .htaccess (if not exist create a
>   .htaccess on laravel root directory)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

You can see [this link](http://tutsnare.com/remove-public-from-url-laravel/) for more help..

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Create a `.htaccess` in the root folder and place:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/puplic/
RewriteRule ^abc/(.*)$ /abc/public/$1 [L,NE]
```

Now , when you request `http://localhost/abc/` it will map request to `http://localhost/abc/public` but the url will not change